# Nhibernate Linq Sum with calculation causes NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate 3.3.3.4001 with SybaseSQLAnywhere12Dialect and trying to use a simple calculation within a sum linq function.

I would like to use Linq rather than HQL to achieve this and would be happy to extend Nhibernate with a default linq to hql generator.

Using the following Linq query raises the exception

> System.NotSupportedException: Expression type 'NhSumExpression' is not supported by this SelectClauseVisitor

**Linq Query**

```
var query = (from c in session.Query<Entity>()
            select c.FieldValue / 100M).Sum()
```

**Expected SQL Statement**

```
SELECT SUM(FieldValue / 100.0) FROM TableName
```

If the same query is run without the Sum() function it performs the calculation correctly, as such am confused why the Sum() wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue when using constants within Linq group function (Max, Min, Sum) functions. If another field is used it will work correctly.

Found bug within NHibernate 3.3.3
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3376

Answer (score 1):

You may try to rewrite your LINQ query a bit, just like this one:

```
var result = ((from c in session.Query<Entity>()
               select c.FieldValue).Sum()) / 100;
```

Resulting query could also be optimized by moving division operator out of the sum:

```
SELECT SUM(FieldValue) / 100 FROM TableName
```

Comment: Thanks, the division outside the sum on the SQL will optimise the query.
The example I gave was too simplified, I need to calculate VAT on a value per row. Unfortunately the legacy database hold VAT percentage as an integer that must be divided by 100 prior to performing the calculation (value * VAT) on each row. As such I must perform the division within the linq query.